# How to use the less than '<' in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

Well, as in the question, how to properly use the '<' in xsl, the one that is placed is '& lt', but even so I can't get it to work, what I try to do is that the songs that last less than 5 min are shown per screen but I can't quite make it work:

Here I attach the xml and xsd code

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type ="text/xsl" href = "ejercicio2parte4.xslt"?>
<musica>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Los magroños</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Julian</artista>
            <nombre_cancion>El cairo</nombre_cancion>
            <duracion>4.50s</duracion>
            <nombre_cancion>Tunez</nombre_cancion>
            <duracion>4.50</duracion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <año_de_publicacion>2004</año_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Scarecrow</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Avantasia</artista>
            <nombre_cancion>Scarecrow</nombre_cancion>
            <duracion>7.11</duracion>
            <nombre_cancion>I dont belive in your love</nombre_cancion>
            <duracion>4.50</duracion>
        <sello_discografico>AFM Records</sello_discografico>
        <año_de_publicacion>1999</año_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
</musica>
```

AND XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>musica</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="grey">
                <th>Titulo del album</th>
                <th>Artista</th>
                <th>nombre cancion</th>
                <th>duracion</th>
                <th>Sello discografico</th>
                <th>Año de publicacion</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="musica/cd">

               <xsl:if test= "duracion &lt; 5.00">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="titulo_del_album"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="artista"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="nombre_cancion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="duracion"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sello_discografico"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="año_de_publicacion"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: which xslt processor do you use? some are broken...

Comment: @MarcStroebel Which ones are "broken"?

Comment: i had some strange results in the past using "web fiddles" like w3schools

Comment: That's not an XSLT processor. It's an implementation of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't quite make it work

It works perfectly well. However, you may be missing the fact that each `cd` in your XML example has **two** `duracion` child elements. In such case your test:

```
duracion &lt; 5.00
```

will return true if **at least one** of the durations is less then 5 minutes - and this is true for both `cd`s in the given example.

OTOH, in XSLT 1.0 the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="duracion"/>
```

will return the string-value of the **first** `duracion` only.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0, only numeric comparisons were supported, not string comparisons. The "<" operator in 1.0 always converted a string argument to a number. If the argument wasn't a number (e.g. "4.50s") it returned NaN, in which case the comparison would always be false. You need to strip the "s" out before comparing to a number, for example by using `translate()` or `substring-before()`.

However, if you have two `duracion` elements and one of them is a number, then the false result doesn't matter, because one true result is enough...